# Some apps are not working with double VPN tunnel

Tags: macos, vpn, dns, openvpn

Im using 2 VPN app simultaneously on my Macbook Air m1, one (OpenVPN) for my job (several corporate services) and second (ProtonVPN) - for my personal purposes (some of music services are not working in my country). It is strange but thats works fine for Google Chrome web-sites surfing, but when Im trying to connect to `Zoom` call or execute `curl` command with any site it looks like I have no access to web. I'm curious what can cause this problem? Intuitively the problem is with DNS resolving, but why it is works fine with web surfing using Google Chrome? Is there any workarounds?

[Here is the comparison of routing tables with different configs. Im a little bit confused which row relate to (for example) Zoom calls?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnZa7.jpg)

Comment: It's trivial for a VPN to be configured to filter out traffic, if you are unable to use Zoom while connected to your work VPN, it's likely a purposeful decision by the Administrator of the VPN.

Comment: @Ramhound I can use Zoom with one of VPN apps enable, but cannot with both

Comment: I am guessing it works with the ProtonVPN and not your work VPN? Which goe back to my statement you should contact your System Administrator at work.

Comment: @Ramhound no, with any of VPNs separately its works fine, but not simultaneously

Comment: By "double VPN tunnel", do you mean that one VPN is started inside the other, or that they work side-by-side?

Comment: @harrymc they are working side-by-side : launch first one, then launch second one

Comment: You should check the route table to understand what's happening.

Comment: @harrymc I attached routing tables. Any suggestions about where should I move next?